# How to print a string in a character array?

Tags: java, 2d-games

I am working on the tortoise and hare game, and everything works except I want to print out "OUCH" when the hare and the tortoise are in the same position. My race track is a character array so I can only put 'O', and whenever I try to print it as a string "OUCH" it prints it as a separate new line. Is there a way to print "OUCH" without breaking up the flow of the game, and outputting it on a different line to everything else?

```
public static int turtlePosition = 0;        // Turtle location
public static int harePosition = 0;          // Hare location
public static char[] track = new char [70];  // Array for Track


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("AND THEY ARE OFF!!");

    while (!gameOver()){

        for (int i = 0; i < track.length; i++){

            track[i] = '-';
        }

        Random random = new Random();
        int r = random.nextInt(10) + 1;

        turtleMove(r);
        hareMove(r);

        if (gameOver()){
            break;
        }

        track[turtlePosition] = 'T';
        track[harePosition] = 'H';

        if (turtlePosition == harePosition){
            String str = String.valueOf(track[turtlePosition]);
            str = "OUCH";
            System.out.println(str);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < track.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(track[i]);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    if (turtlePosition >= 70 && harePosition >= 70){
        System.out.println("IT'S A TIE!!");
    }
    else if (turtlePosition >= 70){
        System.out.println ("TORTOISE WINS!!");
    }
    else {
       System.out.println ("HARE WINS!!");
    }
```

Comment: you need System.out.print() method and also add the whole code so we can understand what you want to achieve

Comment: I think your best bet would be to change your array of char to an array of string, that way when the hare and tortoise are in the same location, set their content to the value “OUCH” and your for loop will print it when it gets to it. Otherwise, if you are determined to use a char array you would need to do the same thing except set the value to ‘O’. Then in the for loop when a character in the array is equal to ‘O’ - system.out.print(“OUCH”); The downside is you would need to constantly check each element in your array which is arguably unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't believe so but you could put a text area to the side.

like this:

Code changes:

```
        if (turtlePosition>=6 || harePosition>=6){
            turtlePosition = 7;
            harePosition = 7;
        }

        track[turtlePosition] = 'T';
        track[harePosition] = 'H';
        
        if (turtlePosition == harePosition){
            insertintotrack("OUCH |");
        }else {
            insertintotrack("     |");
        }
```

New Function:

```
public static void insertintotrack(String in)
{
    char[] info = in.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        track[i] = info[i];
    }
}
```